# I restored my WordPress website but now when I login as admin I don't get my admin panel. Any solutions?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I just restored my WordPress website, but somehow I am not able to get into admin panel even after using correct credentials.
It shows me as logged in, but do not allow me to go into admin panel. Neither it shows me options on the top of the website.

Here is the screenshot
https://gyazo.com/0497b96e2aa8d1b857569091d4850e6a

Any solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are still showing as admin in users rite ?

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the top-left side of the page. you will get an option to goto dashboard. I write this answer because i couldn't comment 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pthao.jpg)